Intensity of Audioreactive low
I am quite new to Blender and trying to animate a mesh through using 'Bake to F Curves' (or, as per the update, 'Sound to Samples').
I am not the best at Blender and don't know how to code. So far, I have gotten great results by adding a 'Deform' modifier, then Baking the sound to that deform.
However, I am trying a specific sound with a photogrammetry mesh and the audio-deformation / reactivity stays super low (only  like a vibration) instead of really emphasising and exgaggerating the shape and deforming the mesh.
When I manually deform the mesh it works fine, so I believe it's to do with the way I'm importing the sound. The sound is mid-range and I've tried to change the frequencies upon importing the sound, but it hasnt helped.
Any recommendations? Please and thank you!

For example, the 'strength' on the deform can go to -100 and +100. However, the audio never deforms it past 0.5/0.9.
